# What's the equivalent of Java substring in C#?

Tags: c#, substring

When I want to do a `substring` to find a region of text in a string in Java, I supply two indexes, one for the `start`, and one for the `end`, but in C#, I am forced to provide length of the `substring` as a parameter, however this becomes a problem if I don't know where I'm supposed to stop, leading me to have things like this:

```
verse[i].Substring(verse[i].IndexOf("start"), (verse[i].IndexOf("end") - verse[i].IndexOf("start"));
```

*instead of just*

```
verse[i].Substring(verse[i].IndexOf("start"), (verse[i].IndexOf("end"));
```

Annoyingly I have come across this issue over and over again and I wonder if I'm the only one or there's a trick I'm not aware of. How best would you go about solving this issue? (Taking cleanliness and speed into consideration)

ps: I don't like creating variables for nearly everything. Thanks

Comment: You can use extension methods. google it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write your own extension method like this

```
var newstr = str.MySubString(start,end);
```

..

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static string MySubString(this string s,int start,int end)
    {
        return s.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @nawfal his arguments are **int** s. See the `IndexOf`

Comment: You're right, din seem though at the first glance. Canceled.. :)

Comment: nawfal was right, the arguments are `string` s not `int` s. This answer is like a repetition of the problem, Take a closer look at the question. I wan't to be able to just use `start` and `end` (strings) to get the substring in one statement.

Comment: @rtuner Take a closer look at the answer. It works similar to Java's substring `str.MySubString(start,end);` :)

Comment: Lol, nice. But it's just repeating what I am avoiding i.e. (start, end - start + 1).. I don't think it's performance wise.

Comment: @rtuner What performance problems do you have? have you measured how much  extra cost would execution of `end-start` bring you?

Comment: On a serious note, this does not answer my question. Rather than recopy an extension method like this all the time I want to do a substring, I can just copy and paste the parameters like in the first example, lengthy code doesn't really hurt me if it doesn't affect performance.

Comment: @rtuner It's an extension method (note that `this string` is the first parameter). You only need to define it once and it will apply to all of your strings.

Comment: @UlfLindback, No it is correct. I rolled it back. I prefer comments before editing my answer.

Comment: in java "0123".substring(0, 1) = "0" though

Comment: I was using your method and I got out of bounds exception as well. +1 definitely breaks the code and provides incorrect results. I adjust your code without +1 and solved the problem :D

Answer (score 12):

The answer you accepted is wrong, because you asked it wrong.

In java when you call substring(START, END) you get a substring starting at START and ending at END - 1.

in c# you just have to call like:

```
Substring(START, END - START);
```

If you add 1 as suggested, you will get a different string.

Answer (score 3):

The OP asked "What's the equivalent of Java substring in C#"? I was happy to see the response since I was converting a Java method that used String.substring, into C#. However, according to the official Java docs, [The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex -1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) 
This was not just a minor difference to me as I wanted to convert Java to C# with the least effort. The extension mentioned above is a great answer, and certainly I could live with that. But for my needs, a more precise Java-like version should be return s.Substring(start, end - start); not start+1

Using the Java doc examples, a test shows this is correct:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestSubString()
    {
         Assert.AreEqual("urge", "hamburger".MySubstring( 4, 8));
        Assert.AreEqual("mile", "smiles".MySubstring(1, 5));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string MySubstring(this string s, string start, string end)
    {
        int startI = s.IndexOf(start);
        int endI = s.IndexOf(end, startI);
        return s.Substring(startI, endI - startI + 1);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
string helloWorld = "startHello Worldend".MySubstring("start", "end");
string vers = verse[i].MySubstring("start", "end");
```

Sometimes extension methods are saving your life. You should only be aware, that if the static class is public and in your namespace, everyone using your namespace also gets your extensions.